# Possible to authenticate an AWS Cognito user via the API?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk

JavaScript/AWS here, although this is more of an **AWS API** question (since the JavaScript SDK just implements the API).

I'm looking at the [AWS Cognito JavaScript SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-cognito-identity-provider/index.html) and trying to figure out how to programmatically authenticate a user given:

- a username
- a password
- a user pool ID

But nothing obvious is jumping out at me. Is this not possible to do through their API/SDK? Do they force you to login from a web form?! Thanks in advance for any-and-all-steering!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there are couple of options that we can use here.

Let me provide examples with [InitiateAuthCommand](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-cognito-identity-provider/classes/initiateauthcommand.html) and [AdminInitiateAuthCommand](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-cognito-identity-provider/classes/admininitiateauthcommand.html).

[**InitiateAuthCommand**](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-cognito-identity-provider/classes/initiateauthcommand.html):

In order to user this, we should enable `ALLOW_USER_PASSWORD_AUTH` in the app client. This can be used in [client-side authentication flow](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-authentication-flow.html#amazon-cognito-user-pools-client-side-authentication-flow).

```
   return new CognitoIdentityProviderClient({region: "<aws-region>"}).send(
        new InitiateAuthCommand({ 
            ClientId: "<the client id of the app>",
            AuthFlow: AuthFlowType.USER_PASSWORD_AUTH,
            AuthParameters: {
                USERNAME: "<user@example.com>",
                PASSWORD: "<password>",
            },
        })
    )}
```

[**AdminInitiateAuthCommand**](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-cognito-identity-provider/classes/admininitiateauthcommand.html):

In order to user this, we should enable `ALLOW_ADMIN_USER_PASSWORD_AUTH` in the app client. Also we have to configure the AWS credentials in the execution environment. So this can be used in [Server-side authentication flow](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-authentication-flow.html#amazon-cognito-user-pools-server-side-authentication-flow)

```
 return new CognitoIdentityProviderClient({region: "<aws-region>"}).send(
     new AdminInitiateAuthCommand ({
         ClientId: "<the client id of the app>",
         AuthFlow: AuthFlowType.ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH,
         UserPoolId:"<the user pool id>",
         AuthParameters: {
                USERNAME: "<user@example.com>",
                PASSWORD: "<password>",
         },
     })
 )}
```

**NOTE:** You can change the `AuthFlow` based on your requirement. Please read [User pool authentication flow](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-authentication-flow.html), [InitiateAuthCommandInput.AuthFlow](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-cognito-identity-provider/interfaces/initiateauthcommandinput.html#authflow) and [AdminInitiateAuthCommandInput.AuthFlow](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-cognito-identity-provider/interfaces/admininitiateauthcommandinput.html#authflow) for more details.